# AsDataView Does Not Show Up

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I would like to return the linq result as a dataview, But AsDataView does not show up as a property in intellisense. I do have System.Data.DataSetExtensions as a reference

```
var qry = from s in MedianDB.tblCountries.AsEnumerable() select s;
DataView dv = qry.AsDataView(); //error here
```

Answer (score 1):

AsDataView is a DataTable extension method.
you should work on the DataTable directly:

```
DataView dv = MedianDB.tblCountries.AsDataView();
```